# Integration over all directions in spontaneous emission, complex dipole element and polarization vectors

Tags: angular-momentum, symmetry, photon-emission, spherical-harmonics

When calculating the rate of spontaneous emission in the Weisskopf-Wigner theory the time derivative of the excited state is related to a sum of couplings to all modes (directions and polarizations) of the electromagnetic field. See [for example](https://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/personalhomes/palffy/Files/Spontaneous.pdf).
The sum is converted to a 3D integral which can be expressed in polar coordinates. The part of the summation/integral I am concerned with is this:

$$
I = \sum_{s=1}^2 \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} |\langle \boldsymbol{d}, \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{\boldsymbol{k},s} \rangle|^2 \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi
$$

Here I've used $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to denote the inner product between two possibly complex valued vectors. I want to evaluate this integral allowing $\boldsymbol{d}$ and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k},s}}$ to be complex in case $\boldsymbol{d}$ represents the transition dipole moment between atomic states with different angular momenta ($\Delta m= \pm 1$) or $\boldsymbol{\epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k},s}}$ represents the polarization vector for circularly polarized light.

\begin{align}
\langle \boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\rangle = A_x^*B_x + A_y^*B_y + A_z^*B_z = \boldsymbol{A}^*\cdot \boldsymbol{B}
\end{align}

The conclusion is often reached that this integral is given by

$$
I = \frac{8\pi}{3} |\boldsymbol{d}|^2
$$

Sometimes this is argued as being to due to the isotropy of the electromagnetic field.
In the article linked above the argument is made by arguing

$$
\boldsymbol{d} = \langle \boldsymbol{d},\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{\boldsymbol{k},1}\rangle\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{\boldsymbol{k},1} + \langle \boldsymbol{d},\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{\boldsymbol{k},2}\rangle\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{\boldsymbol{k},2} + \langle \boldsymbol{d},\boldsymbol{\kappa}\rangle\boldsymbol{\kappa}
$$

with $\boldsymbol{\kappa} = \frac{\boldsymbol{k}}{|\boldsymbol{k}|}$ (it is assumed $\boldsymbol{k}$ is real for far-field light). Then noting (by squaring the above expression

$$
\sum_{s=1}^2 |\langle \boldsymbol{d}, \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{\boldsymbol{k},s}\rangle|^2 = |\boldsymbol{d}|^2 - |\langle \boldsymbol{d}, \boldsymbol{\kappa}\rangle|^2
$$

If $\boldsymbol{d}$ is real then the spherical coordinates for the integration can be chosen such that $\boldsymbol{d}$ points along the $\theta=0$ polar axis so that $\theta$ measure the angle between $\boldsymbol{d}$ and $\boldsymbol{k}$ so that

$$
\langle\boldsymbol{d},\boldsymbol{\kappa} \rangle = |\boldsymbol{d}|\cos(\theta)
$$

With which we are able to reduce the integral to

$$
|\boldsymbol{d}|^2 \int \int (1-\cos^2(\theta)) \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi = |\boldsymbol{d}|^2 \int \int \sin^3(\theta)d\theta d\phi = \frac{8\pi}{3} |\boldsymbol{d}|^2
$$

However, it appears to me that this trick only works in the case that $\boldsymbol{d}$ is real. The idea that the inner product gives the angle between two vectors relies on some underlying structure from assuming the vector space is purely real. What direction is $\boldsymbol{d}$ pointing in if it complex and what is the angle with $\boldsymbol{\kappa}$?

### Question

My question is for a slick calculation of this integral in the case that $\boldsymbol{d}$ and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{\boldsymbol{k},s}$ are possibly complex.

### What I've tried

I can expand 
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{d} =& d_x \hat{\boldsymbol{x}} + d_y \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} + d_z \hat{\boldsymbol{z}}\\
\boldsymbol{\kappa} =& \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \hat{\boldsymbol{x}} + \sin(\theta)\sin(\theta) \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} + \cos(\theta)\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}
\end{align}

Then calculate the inner product explicitly, square and perform the integral explicitly. This gives the correct answer but it blows up to many terms and is pretty messy and unintuitive. It also relies on an explicity expansion in the Cartesian basis which I am trying to avoid. It seems to me like there should be some symmetry arguments that allow us to calculate this without going into a specific basis representation at any point.